# birt report with date month function

Tags: birt

BIRT my question is  when i select parameter in list box it have to compare a value in chart 
it have to produce a result...

for example if i am having a **one list box** i.e select month: **jan 2013,feb 2013,mar 2013** and then **another list box** Period:**Last month,Last year**

when i select a Jan 2013 from one list box and then i wil select Last Month or Last year in another list box 
so result will be Jan 2013 total value and DEC 2012 total value for Last Month
likewise then i will select Last Year Jan 2013 total value and Jan 2012 total value have to display....

thank's in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can user the "Grouped Parameter" option to create parameters that are dependent on preceeding parameters.

In 'outline' right click on 'Report Parameter' and select New Parameter Group

At first glance I don't see anything in the help contents about it.

This Devshare 'Sample BIRT report with cascaded parameter group' should provide a good example. 
http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/devshare/designing-birt-reports/514-sample-birt-report-with-cascaded-parameter-group/